# Would appreciate some help in identifying the language from this snippet

Tags: code-snippets

newbie question here, I'm trying to reuse a code, but since I'm not a programmer I couldn't identify it. I tried googling already some "programming language identifier by syntax" and googling some of the syntax in it and at first I thought it matched vb.net but upon downloading and opening a project there, it had too many syntax errors IIRC, so I don't think this is it.

Here's the snippet:

```
;==============================================================================================================================
; Function:         _MemoryReadStdString($address, $handle, [, $offset=False])
;
; Description:      Read memory for string. If str_length > 15 read pointer else read str.
;
; Parameter(s):     $address - Address in memory to read.
;           $handle - An array containing the Dll handle and the handle of the open
;                       process as returned by _MemoryOpen().
;           $offset - If we wanna read pointer put offset in hex value example:
;           $offset[2] = [0x20, 0x264]
;
; Return Value(s):  On Success - Returns string value
;                   On Failure - Returns empty string ''
;
; Author(s):        Ascer
;===============================================================================================================================
Func _MemoryReadStdString ($address, $handle, $offset)
```

`; read memory for address of our name and return address to this name. 
Local $addr_start = '0x' & Hex(_MemoryPointerRead($address, $handle, $offset)[0], 8)    ;==> example 0x8A16308

    ; read memory for name length, just one byte
Local $str_length = _MemoryRead($addr_start + 0x10, $handle, 'byte')    ;==> 0x8A16308 + 0x10 = 0x8A16318

    ; check if string < 16 then read name from $addr_start
If $str_length < 16 Then
    Return BinaryToString(_MemoryRead($addr_start, $handle, 'char[15]'))    ;==> 'King Medivius'

    ; string length is > 15 then we must read memory($addr_start) for new address
    Else
    $str_pointer = '0x' & Hex(_MemoryRead($addr_start, $handle), 8)    ;==> example 0x8C95320
    Return BinaryToString(_MemoryRead($str_pointer, $handle, 'char[32]'))   ;==> read memory in $str_pointer region to get true name
EndIf

    ; return empty string if nothing found
Return ""`

EndFunc

Sorry about the "EndFunc" there, it's inside the "pre code" but somehow ended up outside it. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_(syntax)#Comments), there are nine languages that use `';'` to introduce a comment. Additionally, if you got the code [here](https://tibiapf.com/forum/bots-and-cheats/opentibia-clients/otclient/365-medivia-discover-battlelist-structure), then it's probably running over something called Cheat Engine. All I did was search the internets ;) for the function name and the author's name.

Answer (score 1):

Googling a portion of the code reveals a possible source at [this post](https://tibiapf.com/forum/bots-and-cheats/opentibia-clients/otclient/365-medivia-discover-battlelist-structure%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) about what seems to be a [Tibia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tibia_(video_game)) private server named [Medivia](https://medivia.online/).

From the context it seems to be written in [AutoIt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoIt) - there is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuyL7.png) near the bottom of the post showing the user testing code using a program named `AutoIt3.exe` [Here](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/) is the download link.